# Stored XSS prevention with rich-text comments using DocumentFragment and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, xss, innerhtml, richtext

I wonder if someone would be able to confirm whether this is safe or not, as I can't seem to find any reference online, nor another question on SO, that specifically deals with this "solution" to XSS.

I need to embed rich-text comments into my page. Obviously the risks of XSS are high, so my plan was to innerHTML a temporary DIV in a DocumentFragment and then recurse the tree, using a pre-defined whitelist of tagNames and attribute names that I have deeemed 'safe', removing any unsafe ones. I can then move this now-safe HTML into my real document.

Is this a safe way of doing it? Is there any way an XSS attack could be triggered by doing this through a DocumentFragment? I'm hoping that it'll be isolated from the real document and hence shielded from user event triggering that might kick off any attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to write your own anti-XSS library as malicious users are bound to know an exploit that you haven't accounted for. I would recommend to use a third party library, for example Google Caja [HTML Sanitiser](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer).

Having looked at your Pen, you code is still vulnerable if the `<` and `>` tags are escaped:

```js
var unsafe = '\u003Cimg src=1 onerror=alert(\u0027XSS_attack_in_progress\u0027)\u003E',
  //var unsafe = '<h3>Hello</h3><h4>World</h4>',
  whitelistTags = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'u'],
  testNode = document.getElementById('testNode');

makeSafeAndAddToDoc(unsafe, testNode);

function makeSafeAndAddToDoc(unsafe, targetParent) {
  var safeDocFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    containerDiv = safeDocFrag.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV")),
    nextChild;
  containerDiv.innerHTML = unsafe;
  while ((nextChild = containerDiv.firstChild)) {
    if (isSafe(nextChild)) {
      safeDocFrag.appendChild(containerDiv.firstChild);
      console.debug(safeDocFrag.children);
    } else {
      containerDiv.removeChild(nextChild);
    }
  }
  safeDocFrag.removeChild(containerDiv);
  targetParent.appendChild(safeDocFrag);
}

function isSafe(testNode) {
  var tag = testNode.tagName && testNode.tagName.toLowerCase(),
    isTextNode = testNode.nodeType === 3;
  if (!isTextNode && whitelistTags.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
    console.warn('Removing unsafe element: ', testNode.tagName);
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < testNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (!isSafe(testNode.childNodes[i])) {
      testNode.removeChild(testNode.childNodes[i]);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
#testNode {
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testNode"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not writing an anti-XSS library. I'm asking if the browser will protect me from XSS if I use DocumentFragment as a temporary placeholder while I run through a whitelist of safe tags and attributes. I have no intention of writing an HTML parser to sanitise the HTML myself!

Comment: If this does prove unworkable, then the link to the HTML Sanitiser is certainly welcome ... thank you.

Comment: Your post mentions iterating through a pre-defined whitelist of tag and attribute names. In a way that sounds like writing your own code to handle XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: It also means I can control people's ability to close tables/divs/etc when I don't want them to, which an HTML sanitiser doesn't really do. I can literally let people use formatting elements only (h1, em, i, etc). Maybe the answer is both, but if the HTML sanitiser were redundant in the situation I'm suggesting, then it would be good to not bloat the project unnecessarily!

Comment: I have posted an example of a XSS attack that doesn't use any tags. Would your approach filter that one out ?

Comment: I believe it would, but then that's what my original question is asking!
Here's a slightly cut-down example of the approach: http://codepen.io/MartinDoyleUK/pen/oXNEyp

Comment: I have added an example that shows your code is still vulnerable if the XSS attack escaped `<` or `>`.

Comment: That's only because I was trying to do it quickly and hadn't added in the whitelisted attribute check that I mentioned in my first post, which would handle any on... attributes being injected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76031/discussion-between-jaco-de-groot-and-martin).

Comment: No ... I've seen you are correct. I had thought that a DocumentFragment would prevent on... attributes from running, but onerror is obviously not protected against. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me and to counter my questions!